# How to upload a image to google-lens using python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, binary, base64

I'm trying to scrape **[google-lens](https://images.google.com/)** with python `requests` but can't find the request where it uploads the image or how it is decoded.

The request (which the answer is the image-analysis) is as following:

```py
import requests

cookies = {
    'CONSENT': 'PENDING+XXX',
    'SOCS': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'HSID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'SSID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'APISID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'SAPISID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    '__Secure-1PAPISID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'SID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.',
    '__Secure-1PSID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'SIDCC': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    '__Secure-1PSIDCC': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'AEC': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'NID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'OTZ': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    '__Secure-ENID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'lens.google.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'referer': 'https://lens.google.com/upload?hl=de-CH&re=df&st=1675340672651&plm=ChAIARIMCIDX7p4GEMDxtbYC&ep=gisbubb',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"109.0.5414.120"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Not_A Brand";v="99.0.0.0", "Google Chrome";v="109.0.5414.120", "Chromium";v="109.0.5414.120"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-ua-wow64': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-client-data': 'CJe2yQEIorbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIte3KAQiTocsBCPKCzQEIv4TNAQiAjM0BCIiMzQEI14zNAQiGjc0BCMeNzQEI1Y7NAQj2js0BCNLhrAII8fStAg==',
}

p = "AfVzNa_TGIdeDaL6ZaPXF7Wx8FCDSF8grbjYLUPXuk5_7Ia3vUCoQ5BUa8slWojngiUp-88dvc59Ohx3_22wAH3GXJHgaT-bLnpAm0r-5YjYIErXRCYJJ0ndUQUxxdF1JptYTdjqaEXXRR87igdc_xBCpxGpdXkXrf7Nf226SST0MdF3vF7mmtvJyklqA8494byV6bj_I92D3vihWglO3OV6phVD1zsqVyfSU_qZvtuEPEA59LETwQ4SKlztDy0fMWmBGgCsXiCuz2bWH2bOIRqUFo0stSVAvscHpY0iIVcEyRYQhXBxRkibV6UvnSIK2w_JQZV7TP4AkRRBPCwy2iKu-KJS6R28OZ3ABqIth7IPDLGymZKQ20vl_HPjXBHAgHzZgFLTs-AfR7zkmsnyWQ9FB77YVA"

response = requests.get(
    'https://lens.google.com/search?p='+p+"%3D%3D&ep=gisbubb&hl=en-US&re=df&st=1675340672651&plm=ChAIARIMCIDX7p4GEMDxtbYCCg8IFRILCIDX7p4GENCgvHUKDwgWEgsIgNfungYQkM3CdQoPCBMSCwiA1%2B6eBhCA/MJ1ChAIFBIMCIDX7p4GEOjKj7MC",
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
)
```

The `p` parameter in the url seems to me like data, but:

- Maybe too short for a image?
- I can't decode the string as **Base64** to an image. Any ideas?

`p` in my case is:

```
AfVzNa_TGIdeDaL6ZaPXF7Wx8FCDSF8grbjYLUPXuk5_7Ia3vUCoQ5BUa8slWojngiUp-88dvc59Ohx3_22wAH3GXJHgaT-bLnpAm0r-5YjYIErXRCYJJ0ndUQUxxdF1JptYTdjqaEXXRR87igdc_xBCpxGpdXkXrf7Nf226SST0MdF3vF7mmtvJyklqA8494byV6bj_I92D3vihWglO3OV6phVD1zsqVyfSU_qZvtuEPEA59LETwQ4SKlztDy0fMWmBGgCsXiCuz2bWH2bOIRqUFo0stSVAvscHpY0iIVcEyRYQhXBxRkibV6UvnSIK2w_JQZV7TP4AkRRBPCwy2iKu-KJS6R28OZ3ABqIth7IPDLGymZKQ20vl_HPjXBHAgHzZgFLTs-AfR7zkmsnyWQ9FB77YVA==
```

In the network tab when uploading the image, I can't find any other request with data.

Also, how would I encode a image to such a string using python?

Comment: Any updates here to upload image to lens?

Comment: @bansi923 Nope, not really. I'd recommend using selenium for now

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, the data seems too short for the image (In base 64 format or other codings).
We can not certainly tell what is happening in the Google Image search internal procedures but the following scenario comes to mind (and usually such search systems works like this):

the user first uploads the image to Google lens and google allocates an ID to the uploaded image in its internal database. You will see that ID as `p` parameter in the search URL and your code. Then the image search uses that ID to refer to the uploaded image in its internal database.

Just to make sure that such a tiny string like `p` can not hold the whole image, run `base64.b64encode(open('path/to/image.png', 'rb').read())` and see the result is a very long string.

If you intercept the network tab in Google Chrome more precisely you will notice that the user first is redirected to an address like `https://lens.google.com/upload&re=df&st=some_number_hereplm=intenal_database_identifier` and then the user will be redirected to the main search page with the `p` parameter in the address bar.

So in order to use Google image search best solution is to use the official API and libraries like [this](https://github.com/arrrlo/Google-Images-Search). But if you insist on using the unofficial way, something like selenium can act like a browser and get the parameter you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I think that brings me a step further. I am aware that it would be possible using Selenium. Wonder if it's possible to upload the image, retrieve the ID and the make a request using that ID

Comment: I saw the request you mentioned also, but couldn't find any Image data in it.

Comment: Actually the image is uploaded using the http POST method to the address I mentioned. Use the `method:POST` filter in the network tab to get more details about the uploading of the image. I think it is possible to do the procedure with the code but consider that you may encounter the captcha problem if you send lots of requests.